# Cakephp is failing to auto generate record id on insert

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a very simple join model in cake php. I'm encountering a bug where the ID for each new record inserted is "".

```
 <?php


 App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Subscriber Model
 *
 * @property ChallengeMember $ChallengeMember
 * @property Activity $Activity
 */
class Subscriber extends AppModel {


    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ChallengeMember' => array(
            'className' => 'ChallengeMember',
            'foreignKey' => 'challenge_member_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Activity' => array(
            'className' => 'Activity',
            'foreignKey' => 'activity_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

This is what the table looks like:

```
  public $fields = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'length' => 36, 'key' => 'primary', 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'charset' => 'latin1'),
        'activity_id' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'length' => 37, 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'charset' => 'latin1'),
        'challenge_member_id' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'length' => 37, 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'charset' => 'latin1'),
        'indexes' => array(

        ),
        'tableParameters' => array('charset' => 'latin1', 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'engine' => 'InnoDB')
    );
```

When testing,

```
$this->Subscriber->create(array('challenge_member_id' => 'test123456','ChallengeMember.first_time_in_dash' => '1'));
$this->Subscriber->save();
Debugger::dump($this->Subscriber->find('all'));
```

Outputs

```
array(
        'Subscriber' => array(
            'id' => '',
            'challenge_member_id' => 'test123456',
            'activity_id' => '',
            'created' => '2014-07-16 18:45:14'
        )
        ........
```

As you can see cake is failing too autogen the ID, which is out of character to the rest of my models. Any ideas ? I've re-baked the model and test fixtures but no joy!

Comment: so you are using UUIDs. Does the table field look right? char(36)? What does save() return? debug() that one. PS: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Sorry version is 2.5.1.

Comment: Save returns:array(
 'Subscriber' => array(
  'challenge_member_id' => 'test123456',
  'activity_id' => '122333333',
  'created' => '2014-07-16 19:08:30',
  'id' => '0'
 )
); then when I try and save again I get a dupe primary key error!

Comment: Check your SQL schema of the table. There is your mistake. Otherwise save() would not return this id. `char(36)`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a string for the `id`? by any chance  are you not missing the `auto_increment` on the `id`?

Comment: @vicocamacho always use a string for the id. Cake then auto generates  a 36 char id. I think though as a workaround in this case I might just use a AI int

Comment: have you tried setting your id field as auto_increment?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I never quite got to the bottom of this, the issue only seems to be with the table named "Subscriber". Every other table in has an ID field defined as:

```
'id' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'length' => 36, 'key' => 'primary', 'collate' => 'latin1_swedish_ci', 'charset' => 'latin1')
```

On Model::save(), cakephp auto generates an ID like the one below:

```
53c4fe0c-c38c-4915-a056-111fd1f54a2f.
```

In the end I just set the subscriber `ID` field to "INT(11) Auto Increment", letting mysql take care of key generation. This solved the issue.